# Can such a virus brick a PC?

Tags: windows, security, virus, desktop-computer

Consider a virus that has access to everything (boot sector, files, everything in the PC), but cannot physically damage equipment (EG: Overheat), and the virus is executed in a PC initially with the OS Windows.

Can this virus make your computer hard-bricked? If not, what's stopping it from doing that?

Comment: Yes; Its possible.  I can run an application that patches my BIOS.  If that process fails, the PC won't boot, easy enough to write your own application to patch the BIOS and make it do anything you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Windows versions XP and earlier, where the User Account Control (UAC) was not present, are more vulnerable, because it was easier to get a program to run with higher privileges. On top of that, Windows 95, 98 and ME did not even have the difference of having different privileges. Viruses would have the same permissions as the user itself, and the only thing needed was for the virus to be executed.

Now, keep in mind, that for a virus, if you run the program and it immediately trashes the PC, the virus itself dies too. A virus does want to survive, so its primary goal is to spread rather than to cause havoc. However, if a virus has survived and knows it has spread, it might cause havoc at some point, although most viruses do not gain from destroying a computer. They gain far more if the virus remains active and leaks information to a remote server or worse, allow access to a hacker through the virus (also known as a back door)

Programs that completely brick a PC when made were usually a prank from one friend to another and honestly, I can't call them a virus because the primary goal of a virus (like in the real world) is to spread and survive.

In theory, if a program is able to infect the BIOS itself, a pc can be altered into such degree that the pc can be thrown away. This used to be popular in the early DOS ages when spreading was not the primary goal. The primary goal of a virus back then was to simply destroy a pc, because the user did something they should not do (run a cracked game, where they should buy the original. The crack was deliberately infected with a virus to discourage users from cracking games, amonst others)

Comment: (1) I believe that the term “Trojan Horse” refers to malware that disguises itself as benign software that a user would choose to run, like a game.  I believe that the type of malware that provides ongoing remote access to the hacker (which you mention in your second paragraph) is more accurately called a “back door”. (2) The question is somewhat unclear, but I believe that it is trying to ask, not whether malware can cause trouble, but whether it can damage a PC so badly that it cannot be recovered — not even with install media and backups.  Obviously, your answer does not address that issue.

Comment: @Scott : I use the term Trojan Horse even more loosely.  e.g., software that disguises itself as non-benign, but is actually even worse than what it disguises itself to be.  The main elements of a Trojan Horse are: A) having its full purpose being hidden, B) having the full results be unpleasant, and probably also C) deception

Comment: @TOOGAM: OK, but how does that make sense?  If a user stumbles across a program that *admits* that it’s going to recruit his machine into a botnet to perform DDoS attacks, why would he choose to run it?  That’s not an effective way to get your keystroke logger, file extractor, or ransomware malware onto people’s PCs.

Comment: @Scott: Drug dealers are known to do this.  Give them some illegal drug (pot), laced with something else (cocaine).  Buyer's don't think they're buying lettuce.  The buyers know they're getting something that much of society deems unethical, yet they just don't know the full story.  Another example: program claims to install a back door for you.  Program actually also installs a back door for program's distributor.  This is not even being advertised as a non-benign program, but there is still the "Trojan Horse" aspect.

Comment: I've edited my post to make some changes in order to make things more clear based on the comments.

Answer (score -1):

There are many types of viruses which are to control the access your computer without your permission such as RAT(remote access Trojan). But not any effect on your system's H/W.

To identify this virus is very difficult task, because this type of virus not display in your system. With the help of this virus intruder manage all activities of your system without your knowing.

**Perform task are:**

- Control confidential information like as debit, credit, and other
  personal security.
- Caught your personal screenshots
- Can be performed formatting your drive.
- Can be downloading and change some privacy files.

[To detect RAT virus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/dd632947(v=technet.10))

Comment: This doesn't really address what was asked in the question.

Comment: [It would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Your answer, however doesn't address what's asked and can be deleted because it doesn't bring any useful information.